# getting input element by element in an array

Tags: c#

it trying to get input element by element, not line by line and display as matrix.
input format is

i would like to get output in the form of square matrix of 3 row and 3 columns

```
100
----------
010
----------
001
```

code:

```
using System;  
public class Exercise14  
{  
    public static void Main() 
{
    int i,j;
    int[,] arr1 = new int[3,3];

       Console.Write("\n\nRead a 2D array of size 3x3 and print the matrix :\n");
       Console.Write("------------------------------------------------------\n");  


    /* Stored values into the array*/
       Console.Write("Input elements in the matrix :\n");
  for(i=0;i<3;i++)
  {
      for(j=0;j<3;j++)
      {

          arr1[i,j] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); 
      }
  }  

 Console.Write("\nThe matrix is : \n");
  for(i=0;i<3;i++)
  {
      Console.Write("\n");
      for(j=0;j<3;j++)
           Console.Write("{0}\t",arr1[i,j]);
     }
   Console.Write("\n\n");
   }
}
```

Comment: What is your problem? Do you have an error? What output did you expect?

Comment: my output is  49 48 48 
10 48 49 
48 10 48 
 in the form of matrix . im expecting a identity matrix as output

Comment: There's nothing in your code to compute an identity matrix.